# jQuery - Grab a <div> ID and distribute it to its children

Tags: jquery, variables, attr, each

I've been trying to grab the #id of a DIV and pass it to each of it's children with jQuery to no avail.

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery-1">
    <a href="link_1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="link_2">Link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="gallery" id="gallery-2">
    <a href="link_1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="link_2">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

turns into..

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery-1">
    <a ref="gallery-1" href="link_1"><img src="#"/></a>
    <a ref="gallery-1" href="link_2"><img src="#"/></a>
</div>
<div class="gallery" id="gallery-2">
    <a rel="gallery-2" href="link_3"><img src="#"/></a>
    <a rel="gallery-2" href="link_4"><img src="#"/></a>
</div>
```

I'm using..

```
$("div.gallery").each(
    function(){
    var galleryCount = $("div.gallery");    
    $("div a:has(img)").attr( "rel", galleryCount );
    }
);
```

..but that just ends up giving me [ object, Object ]. It looks like it's counting both div.gallery's and trying to assign both of them to rel. 
How do I grab just the parent id and apply it to it's children?

Comment: Ok there aren't enough green check marks to go around on this one, so future n00bs that stumble on this page try everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to apply the id of each parent to the rel attribute of it's children? Try:

```
$('.gallery').each(function () {
    $(this).find('a').attr('rel', $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj3px/)**

Comment: This also works, and this one is easier for me to read. ..so .find, finds whats inside .gallery correct?

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to start fiddling with that more.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gallery").each(function(){
        rel = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).find("a").attr("rel",rel)
    });
});
```

Comment: There are so many right answers, it's amazing I didn't fall into one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is:

```
$("div.gallery").each( function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('id'); // <-- Get the ID attribute

    $this.children("a").attr("rel", id);
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/75E7r/1/).

Comment: You're still setting the rel attribute of all `a`s instead of just the children.

Comment: This applies the first gallery id to all links. :( or atleast it did in my test.

Edit: you people are quick!

Comment: The working example I've included just does exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested):

```
$("div.gallery").each(function(){
    var galleryId = $(this).attr('id');    
    $("a:has(img)", this).attr( "rel", galleryId);
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked! Could you explain why exactly? I get that.. using this selects div.gallery, and get it's id via .attr, but i'm not clear on what the second this is doing.

Comment: The second parameter of the `$`/`jQuery` function is a context. You could also use `$(this).find('a:has(img)')`

Comment: Looks like I have to hit the books harder. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take the children, add the rel-attribute, change the inner html to img.

```
$(".gallery").children().each(function(){
    $(this).attr("rel", $(this).parent().attr("id"));
    $(this).html("<img src='#'>");
});
```

outputs:

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery-1">
    <a ref="gallery-1" href="link_1"><img src="#"/></a>
    <a ref="gallery-1" href="link_2"><img src="#"/></a>
</div>
<div class="gallery" id="gallery-2">
    <a rel="gallery-2" href="link_3"><img src="#"/></a>
    <a rel="gallery-2" href="link_4"><img src="#"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This also works, although in my current circumstance it's easier if I don't have to explicitly put each image in the javascript. Incomplete question on my part. Thank you!